# spring boot adding another properties file to the environment

Tags: java, spring, properties

I was wondering if it was possible to add another properties file to the environment path besides just the application.properties file. If so how do you specify the new path? So you can access the properties using the Autowired Environment variable. Currently in my java project the default properties file application.properties have the path /soctrav/src.main.resources/application.properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify additional property files with command line parameters:

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties
```

Take a look at [Application properties file Spring Boot doc chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do it without command line parameters, this will do the trick.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
        @PropertySource("classpath:anotherbunchof.properties")
})
public class YourApplication{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that makes the properties available in the spring environment as well as providing support for using them in `@Value("${my.custom.prop}")`

```java
@Bean
protected PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer createPropertyConfigurer(ConfigurableEnvironment environment)
        throws IOException {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer result = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

    FileUrlResource resource = new FileUrlResource(Paths.get("custom-props.properties").toString());
    result.setLocation(resource);
    try (InputStream is = resource.getInputStream()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(is);
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("customProperties", properties));
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is very useful when you are not in a spring boot autoconfigured environment but have access to basic spring features.